# Microsoft Visual Studio Preparation - Element Not Found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Got error "Microsoft Visual Studio Preparation - Element Not Found" after installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. After getting the error, if I try to run an application, Visual Studio goes unresponsive and has to be ended from the Task Manager. I had to uninstall the update to continue with development. Anybody know a workaround? Thanks!